# When event looping is blocking the application from I/O actions?

Tags: javascript

I just read an [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) about the event loop in JavaScript.
I found two contradictive phrases and I would be glad if someone could clarify.

> A downside of this model is that if a message takes too long to
> complete, the web application is unable to process user interactions
> like click or scroll. The browser mitigates this with the "a script is
> taking too long to run" dialog

> A very interesting property of the event loop model is that
> JavaScript, unlike a lot of other languages, never blocks. Handling
> I/O is typically performed via events and callbacks, so when the
> application is waiting for an IndexedDB query to return or an XHR
> request to return, it can still process other things like user input

So, when is the first one true and when is the second one true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct, even though I agree it is somewhat wrongly expressed.

So by points:

1. It's true that if a synchronous task takes too long to complete, the event loop "gets stuck" there and then all other queued tasks can't run till it finishes.
2. Here it is talking about asynchronous tasks so even though an HTTP request, an I/O request or whatever that is async takes too long to process, all the synchronous tasks can keep doing their job, like processing user input

Answer (score 1):

> "A very interesting property of the event loop model is that
> JavaScript, unlike a lot of other languages, never blocks.

This is misleading. Without clever programming, JavaScript would *always* block the UI thread, because runtime logic always blocks the UI, by design. At a smooth sixty frames a second, that means your application logic must always cooperatively yield control (or simply complete execution) within about 16 milliseconds, otherwise your UI will freeze or stutter.

Because of this, most JavaScript APIs that might take a long time (eg. network requests) are designed in such a way to use techniques (eg callbacks, promises) to circumvent this problem, so that they do not block the event loop, avoiding the UI becoming unresponsive.

Put another way: host environments (eg a Web browser or a Node.js runtime instance) are specifically designed to enable the use of an **event-based programming model** (originally inspired by programming environments like Hypercard on the Mac) whereby the host environment can be asked to perform a long-running task (eg run a timer), **without blocking the main thread of execution**, and for your program to be notified later, via an "event" when the long-running task is complete, enabling your program to pick-up where it left-off.

Comment: Your first 2 lines are a *must* in every explanation as to what asynchronous means/does in Javascript. +1

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of code inside Javascript

1. Synchronous (it's like going one by one).
2. Asynchronous (it's like skipping for the future)

**Synchronous code**
You want to find the prime number from 1 to 10000000 with synchronous code you will write a function and that function will perform the calculation and finds out the prime number in the given range but what will happen with synchronous code. The javascript engine is not able to do any task until that task gets finished.

---

**Asynchronous Code**
If you wrap the same code inside a callback or more friendly with the SetTimeout method the javascript put that function inside the event queue and perform the other operation when a certain time came the timeout method fires callback certainly when there is nothing inside the call stack, it will ask event loop to pass the first thing which is inside the event queue. So this more about finding an idle time to perform the heavy operation.

> Use javascript workers to perform heavy mathematics tasks not
> SetTimeout because eventually, it will block the engine when the
> function is inside the call stack.